# Multiple uplink routing on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing

**Objective**

I'm trying to setup some kind of "uninterruptible Internet supply" for a Linux machine. For this reason I'm using two uplinks: a standard wired connection via `eth0`, and additionally a 3G connection which is available via `eth1`. The wired `eth0` connection should be the default connection, while the `eth1` connection should only be used in case of a connection problem via `eth0`. Both interfaces are configured via DHCP.

**Current setup**

I'm having two default routes via `eth0` and `eth1` respectively, and I've assigned a higher metric value to `eth1` so that `eth0` is preferred by default. Basically, this is working fine: when unplugging the ethernet cable from the `eth0` port, the system seamlessly continues to use `eth1` for any Internet access, since it detects that the `eth0` cable became unplugged, and thus can immediately remove the dead `eth0` entries from the routing table (which seems to be the default behavior).

**The problem**

I'm however facing a problem when the wired connection is not directly interrupted at the `eth0` interface itself, but at some later point in the network instead. In this case, the Linux machine of course can't detect that some cable has been unplugged, keeps the `eth0` entries within the routing table, and any Internet connection attempt fails with a "target network unreachable" error.

So, is there some way to tell Linux to immediately discard the `eth0` route if it can't be used to reach the target network? And if yes, how would I detect when the `eth0` connection becomes available again, so that I can switch back from `eth1` to `eth0` again? Is this possible at all?

Thank you very much for any hints!!

Comment: You need to use a script or program to test the connection periodically and make a nuanced decision of whether you want to consider it available or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing protocols are meant to solve this problem in an internal network.  OSPF, etc. find adjacent neighbors and implement a "keep-alive" system - whereby if they don't receive confirmation of keep alives, they assume the route is dead and rewrite routing tables in realtime.

If you control anything beyond `eth0`, consider setting something up like that.  I think `quagga` is the package/software you may want to look into.  There's probably simpler solutions that don't involve routing protocols.

If `eth0` directly goes to the Internet, which is a network you don't control, you'll need to have some sort of scheduled task check for real connectivity (pinging an outside server, etc.) and manually kill your interface or rewrite your routes when unreachability is discovered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't control any devices between eth0 and the Internet uplink. Is there some standard software I can use to rewrite rules on unreachability, or do I need to hack this on my own? If yes, can you point me in the right direction on how to do this?